# Where i can override the OnInit method

Tags: 2013, development, web-part, visual-studio-2012, farm-solution

I need to write the following farm solution to override the InInit method as follow:-

```
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
        {
            var request = HttpContext.Current.Request;
            var response = HttpContext.Current.Response;


            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(request.QueryString["TreeField"])
                && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(request.QueryString["TreeValue"]))
            {
                response.Redirect(String.Format("{0}?TreeField={1}&TreeValue={2}",
                    SPContext.Current.ListItem.ParentList.DefaultViewUrl,
                    request.QueryString["TreeField"],
                    request.QueryString["TreeValue"]));
            }
            else if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(request.QueryString["TreeField"]))
            {
                response.Redirect(String.Format("{0}?TreeField={1}",
                    SPContext.Current.ListItem.ParentList.DefaultViewUrl,
                    request.QueryString["TreeField"]));
            }
            base.OnInit(e);
        }
```

But i am not sure if i can add this code directly inside a wb part or i have to create a farm solution inside Visual studio ?
Thanks

Comment: What do you mean with "directly inside a webpart"? There is no way, by default, to put .net code in a webpart in any means other than with visual studio

Comment: can you provide me with some links on how to develop a farm solution using VS ?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee231546(v=vs.100).aspx